# Check if child Cases have specific status

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I need to make logic, that i can not save Case as solved as long, as there are actvie subcases (child cases).

So I need to check somehow, if child cases are in status, for example 4, and than allow to finish parent Case.

If child cases are all not in status, i need to show error message about "there are opened subcases, you cannot finish this case".

I have a basic method to close case here

```
public PageReference terminate() {
    PageReference result = validateAndResolveToStatus('7');
    // send notification to parent's owner if it's a user on successful save
    if (result != null) {   // save OK
        Case c = (Case) controller.getRecord();
        if (c.ParentId != null) {
            String parentOwnerId = c.Parent.OwnerId;
            if (parentOwnerId.startsWith('005')) {
                sendNotificationToUser(parentOwnerId, 'KLIP_03_ChildCaseSolved_ToParentOwner', c.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And there is a button

```
<apex:commandButton value="Resolved" action="{!terminate}"/>
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you need to check all child cases if they all are completed or not.

```
List<Case> childCaseList = [SELECT ID from Case WHERE ParentID =: c.Id and and Status != '4'];
if(childCaseList.size() > 0) {
    //list size is >0 means you have open child case so you can't close parent case
}
```